# Buttons disappear being affected by animation on sibling elements in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, animation, transform

I'm trying to implement a simple 3D photo gallery by using CSS3. It works well on the IE10+ browser, but it has a little bug on the newest version chrome that the button disappeared when it is clicked. Can anyone tell me how to fix that? Thank you in advance.

```js
window.onload=function(){
  var oWrap=document.getElementById('wrap');
  var oImgs=oWrap.getElementsByTagName('img');
  var oBtns=oWrap.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var iNow=0;
  oBtns[0].onclick=function(){

    oImgs[iNow].style.WebkitAnimation='1s hide';
    oImgs[iNow].className='';
    if (iNow<=0) {
      iNow=oImgs.length-1;
    }
    else{
      iNow--;
    }
    oImgs[iNow].style.WebkitAnimation='1s show';
    oImgs[iNow].className='active';

  };

  oBtns[1].onclick=function(){
    oImgs[iNow].style.WebkitAnimation='1s hide';
    oImgs[iNow].className='';
    if (iNow>=oImgs.length-1) {
      iNow=0;
    }
    else{
      iNow++;
    }

    oImgs[iNow].style.WebkitAnimation='1s show';
    oImgs[iNow].className='active';
  };
};
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyFrames show{
  0%{
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg);
    opacity: 0;

  }
  100%{
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyFrames hide{
  0%{
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100%{
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(-180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#wrap{
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto;
  -webkit-perspective:800px;
}
img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin:bottom;
  -webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg);
  opacity: 0;
}

input{
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  font:20px/40px arial;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
}

#wrap input:nth-of-type(1){
  left: -200px;
  top: 200px;

}
#wrap input:nth-of-type(2){
  right: -200px;
  top:200px;

}
.active{
  -webkit-transform:rotateX(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <img src="img/1.jpg" class="active" />
  <img src="img/2.jpg"/>
  <img src="img/3.jpg"/>
  <img src="img/4.jpg"/>
  <img src="img/5.jpg"/>
  <input type="button" value="Previous" />
  <input type="button" value="Next" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please, next time use stacksnippets or jsfiddle to show your code. you must to read the help of stackoverflow to formule good questions, to avoid closing votes or wrong answers. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me this looks like a bug in current stable Chrome (49.0.2623.110 m). Sibling elements get affected by the animation. Note that in Chrome Canary (which is now 51.0.2694.0) this doesn't reproduce. I think while waiting for a chrome update you can find some workaround. Wrapping buttons in a separate `<div>` worked for me:

```js
window.onload=function(){
  var oWrap=document.getElementById('wrap');
  var oImgs=oWrap.getElementsByTagName('img');
  var oWrap2=document.getElementById('wrap2');
  var oBtns=oWrap2.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var iNow=0;
  oBtns[0].onclick=function(){

    oImgs[iNow].style.WebkitAnimation='1s hide';
    oImgs[iNow].className='';
    if (iNow<=0) {
      iNow=oImgs.length-1;
    }
    else{
      iNow--;
    }
    oImgs[iNow].style.WebkitAnimation='1s show';
    oImgs[iNow].className='active';

  };

  oBtns[1].onclick=function(){
    oImgs[iNow].style.WebkitAnimation='1s hide';
    oImgs[iNow].className='';
    if (iNow>=oImgs.length-1) {
      iNow=0;
    }
    else{
      iNow++;
    }

    oImgs[iNow].style.WebkitAnimation='1s show';
    oImgs[iNow].className='active';
  };
};
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyFrames show{
  0%{
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg);
    opacity: 0;

  }
  100%{
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyFrames hide{
  0%{
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100%{
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(-180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#wrap, #wrap2{
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto;
  -webkit-perspective:800px;
}
 #wrap2{
   margin-top: -400px;
 }
img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin:bottom;
  -webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg);
  opacity: 0;
}

input{
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  font:20px/40px arial;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
}

#wrap input:nth-of-type(1), #wrap2 input:nth-of-type(1){
  left: -200px;
  top: 200px;
}
 #wrap input:nth-of-type(2), #wrap2 input:nth-of-type(2){
  right: -200px;
  top:200px;
}
 
.active{
  -webkit-transform:rotateX(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <img src="img/1.jpg" class="active" />
  <img src="img/2.jpg"/>
  <img src="img/3.jpg"/>
  <img src="img/4.jpg"/>
  <img src="img/5.jpg"/>
</div>
<div id="wrap2">
  <input type="button" value="Previous" />
  <input type="button" value="Next" />
</div>
```